# detect collision with sprite in sprite sheet

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios6, cocos2d-iphone

I have a sprite sheet in which there a four images(bat1,bat2,bat3.bat4) , in Image there is a person with holding the bat and when all images are combined in animation then it looks like playing baseball.
below is the code that i have used to add sprite sheet.

```
[[CCSpriteFrameCache sharedSpriteFrameCache] addSpriteFramesWithFile:@"baseball.plist"];

spriteSheet = [CCSpriteBatchNode batchNodeWithFile:@"baseball.plist"];
[self addChild:spriteSheet];

background = [CCSprite spriteWithSpriteFrameName:@"bat4.png"];
background.position = ccp(220, 185);
background.tag = 10;
[self addChild:background];

for(int i = 1; i < 5; i++) {
        [walkAnimFrames addObject:[[CCSpriteFrameCache sharedSpriteFrameCache]    spriteFrameByName:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"bat%d.png", i]]];
}
```

CCAnimation *walkAnim = [CCAnimation animationWithSpriteFrames:walkAnimFrames delay:5.0f];

```
 self.walkAction = [CCRepeatForever actionWithAction:[CCAnimate actionWithAnimation:walkAnim]];

[background runAction:_walkAction];
```

And i am detecting the collision of ball with bat. by below code

```
for (CCSprite *monster in _monsters) {
        if (CGRectIntersectsRect(background.boundingBox, monster.boundingBox)) {
            if (((background.position.x -5 > monster.position.x + (monster.contentSize.width/2)) && background.position.y > monster.position.y)) {
                isCollision = 1;
                [monstersToDelete addObject:monster];
            }
           // [monstersToDelete addObject:monster];
            //[self addFishToBoat];
        }
    }
```

here wat happen is collision is detected but it always  detect collision with  rect of bat4.. as the bat is moving and the cgrect of all bat is different so even when bas is very much far away from bat1 then it will detect the collision because ball's rect will intersect with rect of bat4.

But i want the collision will de detect only when the ball will collide wiith different bats, i mean when bal hit with bat1,bat2,bat3,bat4 then only it will detect the collision rather then detect with bat4 always

Comment: reduce bounding box of bat4 and try, if bounding box of all the bat are same then it would be possible.

Comment: how to reduce? and one more thing the bats are at difrent angles suppose when i dint touch the screen then bat(bat1) is at 90 degree so its rect will be different but when i start touching then by sprite sheet the other bat (bat2) comes and the bat2 is at angle 60 degree so its rect will be different and so on for other bats till 0 degree. so there will be lots of difference in rect of all so i want to detect collision will correct rect

Comment: CCSprite *bat1Sprite = [CCSprite spriteWithFile:@"bat.jpg" rect:CGRectMake(0, 0, 30, 10)]; and whatever the angle is bounding box remains same all the time.

Comment: but i want this to take bounding box of bat that is colliding with the bat

Comment: image of all the bat are same? am i right? if its true then you need to change the bounding box to get collision, otherwise they would be overlapping at the same location and you cant get specific collision

Comment: no image of bats are not same.. in bat1 the bat is at 90 degree. so its rect will be small in width and large in height. in bat2 the bat is at 60 degree angle the height reduce to some extent but width increase. in bat3 the bat is at angle 45 degree so in this again the height decrease and width increases and so on for other images till the angle become 0..

Comment: in this case as i am using  code 
  background = [CCSprite spriteWithSpriteFrameName:@"bat4.png"];
background.position = ccp(220, 185);
background.tag = 10;
[self addChild:background]; in this case the bat4 rect is large in width and small in height. so when bat is animation its using bats sprite form sprite sheets so bats angle is changing dynamically. hence the rect also changes but the collision is always dtected with bat4 rect

Comment: concern is ccSprite can not have irregular shape, it can only have rect shape, thats why it creates problem with Colission, if you want specific colission then use box2d which allows irregular shaped body. whatever the angle of your sprite image, it considers it in rect.

Comment: ohk thanks. but i have created whole game with cocos2d ...so its difficult to use box2d ..

Answer (score 0):

Here is great tutorials by raywenderlich on [sprites collision detection](http://www.raywenderlich.com/606/how-to-use-box2d-for-just-collision-detection-with-cocos2d-iphone).

Or

You can try this tutorial also [Sprite Collision](http://www.cocos2d-x.org/projects/cocos2d-x/wiki/Chapter_5_-_How_to_Detect_the_Collisions)

Hope these will help you.

Answer (score 0):

You try this code it may help you...

```
_contactListener = new MyContactListener();
_world->SetContactListener(_contactListener);

// Preload effect
[[SimpleAudioEngine sharedEngine] preloadEffect:@"hahaha.caf"];



std::vector<b2Body *>toDestroy; 
std::vector<MyContact>::iterator pos;
for(pos = _contactListener->_contacts.begin(); 
    pos != _contactListener->_contacts.end(); ++pos) {
    MyContact contact = *pos;

    b2Body *bodyA = contact.fixtureA->GetBody();
    b2Body *bodyB = contact.fixtureB->GetBody();
    if (bodyA->GetUserData() != NULL && bodyB->GetUserData() != NULL) {
        CCSprite *spriteA = (CCSprite *) bodyA->GetUserData();
        CCSprite *spriteB = (CCSprite *) bodyB->GetUserData();

        if (spriteA.tag == 1 && spriteB.tag == 2) {
            toDestroy.push_back(bodyA);
        } else if (spriteA.tag == 2 && spriteB.tag == 1) {
            toDestroy.push_back(bodyB);
        } 
    }        
}

std::vector<b2Body *>::iterator pos2;
for(pos2 = toDestroy.begin(); pos2 != toDestroy.end(); ++pos2) {
    b2Body *body = *pos2;     
    if (body->GetUserData() != NULL) {
        CCSprite *sprite = (CCSprite *) body->GetUserData();
        [_spriteSheet removeChild:sprite cleanup:YES];
    }
    _world->DestroyBody(body);
}

if (toDestroy.size() > 0) {
    [[SimpleAudioEngine sharedEngine] playEffect:@"hahaha.caf"];   
}
```

Fore more detail about this code visit

http://www.raywenderlich.com/606/how-to-use-box2d-for-just-collision-detection-with-cocos2d-iphone